# Why the sprites in my game does not show?

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

Hi i am using the SFML library to make a game but i am having problem trying to show a vector of "enemies"

here is the code:

enemy.h:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Enemy {
private:
 sf::Texture texture;
 sf::Sprite enemySprite;

 float enemySpeed;
 int maxY, maxX;
public:
 Enemy(int _maxY, int _maxX);
 void render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd);
 void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
 void reset(float speed);
};

#endif
```

enemy.cpp:

```
#include <ctime>

Enemy::Enemy(int _maxY, int _maxX) {
texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-
master/03_World/Media/Textures/Raptor.png");
enemySprite.setTexture(texture);
enemySprite.rotate(180);

maxY = _maxY;
maxX = _maxX;
}

void Enemy::render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd){
wnd->draw(enemySprite);
}

void Enemy::reset(float speed){
srand(time(NULL));
int num = rand();

enemySpeed = speed;

enemySprite.setPosition(num%maxX, maxY);
}

void Enemy::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
enemySprite.move(0.0f, enemySpeed * deltaTime.asSeconds());

if (enemySprite.getPosition().y > 600){
reset(enemySpeed);
}
}
```

Game.h:

```
  class Game {
private:
 sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;
 Aircraft aircraft;
 std::vector<Enemy> enemies;

 void reset();
 private:
 void proccesEvent();
 void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
 void render();
 public:
 Game();
 void run();
 };
```

Game.cpp:

```
Game::Game(){
mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "ventana SFML"); 

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
   enemies.push_back(Enemy(800, 600));
}
}

void Game::proccesEvent(){
sf::Event event;

while(mWindow->pollEvent(event)){
 if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
    mWindow->close();
  }
 }
}

void Game::reset(){
 for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
   enemies[i].reset(100.0f);
 }
}

void Game::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)){
aircraft.Up();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)){
aircraft.Down();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
aircraft.Left();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)){
aircraft.Right();
}

aircraft.update(deltaTime); 

for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
enemies[i].update(deltaTime);
}
}

void Game::render(){
mWindow->clear();
aircraft.Render(mWindow);
for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
enemies[i].render(mWindow);
}
mWindow->display();
}

void Game::run(){
sf::Clock clock;
while(mWindow->isOpen()){
sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();

proccesEvent();
reset();
update(deltaTime);
render();
}
}
```

the problem is that the "enemies" doesn't appear on the screen. the textures are load correctly and if i remove the function reset from the function run in the class Game a white square appear instead of the texture and one at the time, so how can i correct this so multiple enemies are show at the same time.

Comment: is this line :  for (int i=0; enemies.size(); i++) doing what you want it to do in regards to the conditional clause?  Does enemies.size() reach zero to terminate the loop?

Comment: yes i corrected that line, i forgot to added here. the problem still the same

Comment: Is your texture actually loading? I would add an if check there and do a test with that to see.  `if (!texture.loadFromFile("texture.png")) // error checking code`

Comment: I did that already and, yes, the textures are loading.

Comment: Do me a favor, set your sprite's position to the middle of the screen in your constructor, set your speed to 10 also in the constructor, and let me know if you can see any of the enemy sprites.

Comment: also why are you resetting the enemy every frame? I thought this code looked familiar.